# VMware ESXI cpu and memory addition

Tags: vmware-esxi, hardware, upgrade

I am looking to install the free version of ESXI on my server but am possibly upgrading it in the future.  I currently have 1 CPU and 48GB of RAM.  I would be looking to add another CPU and memory for it.  Would ESXI be able to handle the upgrade or would I have to reinstall it so it could see the 2nd CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware will recognize your new hardware upon reboot.

You won't need to make any changes to the ESXi configuration for the hardware changes you've described.